# Draw arc with 2 points and center of the circle

Tags: java, drawing, geometric-arc

I have two points of circle and center of this circle. I want to draw an arc between these points. Method `drawArc` is to simple and doesn't fit my purpose.
Anybody help?

Comment: Is this homework? If so please tag it as such.

Comment: I know that exists meny functions to draw Arc, but I can't fint suitable

Answer (score 28):

You can use Canvas.drawArc, but you must compute the arguments it needs:

Lets say that the center of the circle is (x0, y0) and that the arc contains your two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2). Then the radius is: r=sqrt((x1-x0)*(x1-x0) + (y1-y0)*(y1-y0)). So:

```
int r = (int)Math.sqrt((x1-x0)*(x1-x0) + (y1-y0)*(y1-y0));
int x = x0-r;
int y = y0-r;
int width = 2*r;
int height = 2*r;
int startAngle = (int) (180/Math.PI*atan2(y1-y0, x1-x0));
int endAngle = (int) (180/Math.PI*atan2(y2-y0, x2-x0));
canvas.drawArc(x, y, width, height, startAngle, endAngle);
```

Good luck!

Comment: FYI: This code would work a bit better if you used `float` instead of `int` variables. PI=3.14, Square Roots, etc. You could be creating a lot of zeros if you stick with `int` types.

Comment: in theory yes. however, drawArc() has int parameters.

Comment: Note that r = Math.hypot(x1-x0, y1 - 0)

Comment: Currently this `canvas.drawArc()` has 2 parameters more and is designed for API 21. Use overriden version if you need < 21.

Answer (score 2):

`Graphics.drawArc` expects the following parameters:

- x
- y
- width
- height
- startAngle
- arcAngle

Given your arc start and end points it is possible to compute a **bounding box** where the arc will be drawn.  This gives you enough information to provide parameters: x, y, width and height.

You haven't specified the desired angle so I guess you could choose one arbitrarily.