# Java Circle Shape (6 segments)

Tags: java, paint, geometry

I'm have an idea for a really cool looking UI for the main menu of a game I'm working on. The menu will be a perfect circle centered in the middle of the frame. The circle is divided into 6 equal segments. I attached a poorly made example picture to try and illustrate the concept. Basically just wondering what is the best method for drawing this shape? My first idea was to create an array of points that store each intersection and then just draw lines between them. Also, I sucked at trig so any advice for how to get exact measurements would be very helpful.

I'm trying to incorporate this idea within the creation of this menu. Any thoughts on how to pull it all together? [Draw arc with 2 points and center of the circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196749/draw-arc-with-2-points-and-center-of-the-circle)

[image: example of menu]

Comment: Trig would come in very handy here.  Hint:  Each sixth of the circle is in 2*pi/6 steps, and the radius of the inner circle is between 0 and 0.25.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to draw this on the fly rather than using pre-made images?

Comment: you want everything to be equal right? I would draw six arcs at 60  degrees each (using Graphics fillArc) and then draw a circle in the middle.

Comment: @twain249 not a bad idea, only "issue" is that it would be nice to store each "segment" so I can change the color and maybe (for coolness effect) have the segment pop out from the circle a little when hovered on.

Comment: @mbreen you could create separate `Components` for all the segments and then use the individual's container's `Graphics` and then you can register `Listeners` for the various `Components` to do some manipulation.

Comment: I uploaded a new picture that is a little better than the first one. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What UI toolkit are you using?
Swing/ AWT:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/compositing.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/complexshapes.html

JavaFX: I don't know a good 2d graphics composition tutorial, but as a start:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/shape/package-summary.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/