# How to draw Arc between two points on the Canvas?

Tags: android, android-canvas, ondraw

I have two points in the canvas, now I'm able to draw a line between those points like this below image by using

This code `canvas.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y, paint);`
[image]

I want to draw the arc between two points like below image.

[image]

How can I draw like this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196749/draw-arc-with-2-points-and-center-of-the-circle

Comment: @vajapravin i tried that, but those functions are not available for canvas in android ..

Comment: we have this function in android : drawArc(RectF, float, float, boolean, Paint);

Comment: have you tried http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/08/canvasdrawarc.html... you have to make oval shape on that position

Comment: @vajapravin Your question (and your answer below) would be easier to understand if in the images above the blue dots would have labels p1 and p2.

Comment: I have summarized arc concept on my blog. I hope this will be helpful http://aniruddhambarakar.blogspot.in/2015/10/android-canvas-arc-drawing.html?showComment=1446370425382#c1045773638145532238

Comment: Here is my solution for this problem : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52649091/9112590

Comment: Here is my solution for this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52649091/9112590

Comment: only working for > api 21

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Finally I got the solution from this code:

```
float radius = 20;
final RectF oval = new RectF();
oval.set(point1.x - radius, point1.y - radius, point1.x + radius, point1.y+ radius);
Path myPath = new Path();
myPath.arcTo(oval, startAngle, -(float) sweepAngle, true);
```

To calculate `startAngle`, use this code:

```
int startAngle = (int) (180 / Math.PI * Math.atan2(point.y - point1.y, point.x - point1.x));
```

Here, `point1` means where you want to start drawing the Arc. `sweepAngle` means the angle between two lines. We have to calculate that by using two points like the blue points in my Question image.

Comment: What does sweeep_angle mean?

Comment: Here sweep_angle means the angle between two lines, we have to calculate that by using two points those are shortest points between the corner (i.e like point) like blue points in my Question image...

Comment: HI @RajaReddyPolamReddy , How will I draw somthing in which lines will not appear, only arc will be shown.

Comment: canvas.drawArc(.., .., false, ..) will draw arc without considering drawing of lines connected to its centers.

Comment: @RajaReddy PolamReddy and what will be the "p1"?

Comment: can you please post complete solution?

Comment: Maybe yoy can give any advise for me about this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35845262/advice-about-android-custom-view

Comment: Do anyone know how to calculate sweep angle, we have three  known points.

Comment: Calulated sweepAngle also:

dist = Math.sqrt((p1.x - p2.x) * (p1.x - p2.x) + (p1.y - p2.y) * (p1.y - p2.y)); ;  ;            
sweepAngle = 180- (dist/2)/radius; ; ; ;

Comment: All these methods are usually void, so they do not return anything but just drawing the arc itself. Do you know if it is possible to get, somehow, the coordinates of the points which form the arc?

Answer (score 19):

Do something like this:

```
//Initialized paint on a class level object.
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
//Calculate the rect / bounds of oval
RectF rectF = new RectF(50, 20, 100, 80);

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {      
    //Do the drawing in onDraw() method of View.
    canvas.drawArc (rectF, 90, 45, false, p);
}
```

Comment: Then you need to provide the start angle and sweep angle, see the [docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html)

Comment: the angle between the points will change dynamically and the position of those points also..

Comment: How can I calculate the sweep angle? Could you please update the code to calculate this?

Comment: The 4th parameter to `drawArc` must be false, or otherwise it will draw a wedge. The Style also needs to be `STROKE`.

Answer (score 9):

[image]first we need to visual how the coordinates are in terms of start and sweep angels then it will become more clear.

so if you wanted just the right top piece of the circle, we could do something like this:

```
 val rect = RectF(0f, 0f, 500f, 300f)
        val paint = Paint()
        paint.apply {
            strokeWidth = 5f
            setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE)
            color = COLOR.BLUE
        }
         path.addArc(rect, 270f, 90f)
```

..

this starts at 270 (per the diagram above and 'sweeps` 90 degrees forward. you then have this shape:

[image]

let's create one more so you get the hang of it.  this time let's use a negative value: we want to create a semi half moon (arc) starting from the right side:

```
    path.addArc(rect, 0f, -180f)
```

here we started at 0 and 'sweeped` -180 degrees.
and the results are:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to do something a little different and it's all about calculating sweep and start angles.

I wanted to show an arc that represents progress on a circle that goes from top to bottom.

So I had progress value from 0...100 and I want to show an arc that start from top to bottom to fill the circle when the progress is 100.

To calculate the sweepAngle I use:

```
    int sweepAngle = (int) (360 * (getProgress() / 100.f));
```

Next is to calculate the startAngle

```
    int startAngle = 270 - sweepAngle / 2;
```

Start Angle is calculated this way because:

1. It's always going to start from the left side, starting from the top to bottom. So starting angle at the top equals 270 (Note that it goes clockwise and 0 = 3 o'clock, so 12 o'clock equals 270 degrees)
2. Next I want to calculate how far I'm going to get away from my starting point (270) and to do that I only calculate half of the sweep angle because only half of the arc will be on the left side and the other half on the right side.

So considering I have progress of 25%

```
sweepAngle = 90 degrees (90 degrees is quarter of a circle)
start angle = 225 (45 degrees away from 270)
```

If you want the progress to go from other sides (Left to right, right to left etc..) you will only need to replace 270 with the starting the angle.

Answer (score 2):

I may be late to answer but I got more information.

After **`Android Lollipop`** there are two ways to address this problem

> public void drawArc(RectF oval, float startAngle, float sweepAngle,
>   boolean useCenter, Paint paint)
>
> public void drawArc(float left, float top, float right, float bottom,
>   float startAngle, float sweepAngle, boolean useCenter, Paint paint)

**Usage:**

```
   RectF rectF = new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);

    // method 1
    canvas.drawArc (rectF, 90, 45, true,  paints[0]);

    // method 2
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        canvas.drawArc (left, top, right, bottom, 0, 45, true, paints[1]);
    }
```

**Sweep angle is nothing more than angle of Sector which is drawn clockwise eg. for below code**

```
private void drawArcs(Canvas canvas) {
    RectF rectF = new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);

    // white arc
    canvas.drawArc (rectF, 90, 45, true,  paints[0]);

    // Green arc
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        canvas.drawArc (left, top, right, bottom, 0, 45, true, paints[1]);
    }

    // Red stroked arc
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        canvas.drawArc (left, top, right, bottom, 180, 45, true,  paints[2]);
    }
}
```

Result will look like this

[image]

Same can be achieved with the help of defining Paths and then iterating over them in onDraw method as illustrated in this snippet:

```
 public class ArcDrawable extends Drawable {

    private int left, right, top, bottom;
    private  Paint[] paints = new Paint[3];
    private HashMap<Path, Paint> pathMap = new HashMap();


    public ArcDrawable() {

        // white paint
        Paint whitePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        whitePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paints[0]= whitePaint;

        // green paint
        Paint greenPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        greenPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paints[1]= greenPaint;

        // red paint
        Paint redPaint =new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        redPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        redPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paints[2]= redPaint;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

        //----------USE PATHS----------
        // Define and use custom  Path
        for (Map.Entry<Path, Paint> entry : pathMap.entrySet()) {
            // Draw Path on respective Paint style
            canvas.drawPath(entry.getKey(),  entry.getValue());

        }

        // -------OR use conventional Style---------
        //drawArcs(canvas);

    }


    //Same result
    private void drawArcs(Canvas canvas) {
        RectF rectF = new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);

        // method 1
        canvas.drawArc (rectF, 90, 45, true,  paints[0]);

        // method 2
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            canvas.drawArc (left, top, right, bottom, 0, 45, true, paints[1]);
        }

        // method two with stroke
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            canvas.drawArc (left, top, right, bottom, 180, 45, true,  paints[2]);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
        super.onBoundsChange(bounds);

        int width = bounds.width();
        int height = bounds.height();

        left = bounds.left;
        right = bounds.right;
        top = bounds.top;
        bottom = bounds.bottom;

        final int size = Math.min(width, height);
        final int centerX = bounds.left + (width / 2);
        final int centerY = bounds.top + (height / 2);

        pathMap.clear();
        //update pathmap using new bounds
        recreatePathMap(size, centerX, centerY);
        invalidateSelf();
    }


    private Path recreatePathMap(int size, int centerX, int centerY) {

        RectF rectF = new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);

        // first arc
        Path arcPath = new Path();
        arcPath.moveTo(centerX,centerY);
        arcPath.arcTo (rectF, 90, 45);
        arcPath.close();
        // add to draw Map
        pathMap.put(arcPath, paints[0]);

        //second arc
        arcPath = new Path();
        arcPath.moveTo(centerX,centerY);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
          arcPath.arcTo (rectF, 0, 45);
        }
        arcPath.close();
        // add to draw Map
        pathMap.put(arcPath, paints[1]);

        // third arc
        arcPath = new Path();
        arcPath.moveTo(centerX,centerY);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            arcPath.arcTo (rectF, 180, 45);

        }
        arcPath.close();
        // add to draw Map
        pathMap.put(arcPath, paints[2]);

        return arcPath;

    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {

    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(@Nullable ColorFilter colorFilter) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return 0;
    }


}
```

**Complete source code:**

https://github.com/hiteshsahu/Arc-Drawable

Answer (score 0):

a sample for draw arc.

```
public static Bitmap clipRoundedCorner(Bitmap bitmap, float r, boolean tr, boolean tl, boolean bl, boolean br)
{
    int W = bitmap.getWidth();
    int H = bitmap.getHeight();

    if (r < 0)
        r = 0;

    int smallLeg = W;

    if(H < W )
        smallLeg = H;

    if (r > smallLeg)
        r = smallLeg / 2;

    float lineStop = r/2;

    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(0,0);

    if(tr)
    {
        path.moveTo(0, lineStop);
        path.arcTo(new RectF(0,0, r,r), 180, 90, false);
    }

    path.lineTo(W-lineStop, 0);

    if(tl)
        path.arcTo(new RectF(W-r,0, W,r), 270, 90, false);
    else
        path.lineTo(W, 0);

    path.lineTo(W, H-lineStop);

    if(bl)
        path.arcTo(new RectF(W-r,H-r, W,H), 0, 90, false);
    else
        path.lineTo(W, H);

    path.lineTo(lineStop, H);

    if(br)
        path.arcTo(new RectF(0,H-r, r,H), 90, 90, false);
    else
        path.lineTo(0,H);

    if(tr)
        path.lineTo(0,lineStop);
    else
        path.lineTo(0,0);


    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(W, H, Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
    final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37446243/5320080) by Langkiller. This draws a cubic line from the start point via the control point to the end point.

```
Path path = new Path();
float startX = 0;
float startY = 2;
float controlX = 2;
float controlY = 4;
float endX = 4
float endY = 2
conePath.cubicTo(startX, startY, controlX, controlY,endX, endY);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setARGB(200, 62, 90, 177);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

canvas.drawPath(path, paint)
```