# Draw circle that passes over two points

Tags: android, geometry

I get too points A and B, and I want to draw an arc that passes over the two points (in other words, determinate the circle center coordinate C).
I know the radius, and angle, and the two points coordinates.

I hope I'm clear.

Could you help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131954/how-to-draw-arc-between-two-points-on-the-canvas

Comment: two minute googling result http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/53027.html

Answer (score 1):

You know the distance from two points to the center of the circle (the radius).
Draw two circles with the same radii but with center of these two known points A and B. Where these two circles intersect is the center of the circle you are looking for.

I'm not sure what you mean by "I know the [..] angle"

Comment: "I know the [..] angle" => I get the Arc angle (for example 30°) and radius (for example 50px).

Comment: If you mean the angle between the radii to A and B respectively from the circle center, that is superfluos information if u know the radius. Anyway, with the given information you will have two circles to choose from that meet the requirement.