# How to draw a curve in android

Tags: android, canvas

I want to draw a curve [required output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1a0D.png) like this. But i am getting the output
like this [current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z22xj.png). Here the blue color is the background & the curve is the red colour. here My code.

```
for (i = 10; i <= 360; i = i + 10) {
    new_x = i;
    new_y = (float) Math.sin(new_x / 180.0 * Math.PI);

    canvas.drawLine((float) (old_x / 360.0 * w), 100 + 90 * old_y, (float) (new_x / 360.0 * w), 100 + 90 * new_y, paint);

    old_x = new_x;
    old_y = new_y;
}
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131954/how-to-draw-arc-between-two-points-on-the-canvas

Comment: please tell me the what is the point1.x which class

Comment: Point class which contain x and y value for a particular point.

Comment: Sir, please can you post the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling drawline each time, it might be more optimal to use drawPath:
ie.

```
Path path = new Path();
boolean first = true;
for (i = 10; i <= 360; i = i + 10) {
    new_x = i;
    new_y = (float) Math.sin(new_x / 180.0 * Math.PI);


    if (first) {
        first = false;
        path.moveTo(new_x, new_y);
    }
    else{
        path.lineTo(new_x, new_y);
    }
}
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Then try to use quadTo instead of lineTo, for the points in the middle to smoothen it: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#quadTo(float, float, float, float)