# draw arc between two point

Tags: java, android, draw

I was able to draw four lines between 4 button, now I want to draw arcs or curved lines

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw Arc between two points on the Canvas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131954/how-to-draw-arc-between-two-points-on-the-canvas)

Comment: @sudo 
I did not understand the solution too well