# Polygon with rounded corners

Tags: java, processing, rounded-corners, bezier

I'm using Processing to try to draw something similar to the image below:

[image]

I've seen some examples using `bezierVertex` for regular shapes, like [**this one**](http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/17050), but I would like to build a simple drawing method where I can specify my shape's vertex and then the corner radius. Something like `myRoundedShape(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3... xn, yn, cornerRadius)`
Any ideas?

Comment: Are the (xn, yn) coordinates of the vertices of the unrounded polygon? If yes, this means the rounded polygon does not go thru all the (xn, yn) points, right?

Comment: Yes, they are. The rounded polygon does not go trough the (xn, yn) points.

Comment: Found this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771828/algorithm-for-creating-rounded-corners-in-a-polygon) that might be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need rounded corners for arbitrary angles, Bezier curves are pretty much the worst possible choice, because the maths is stupidly complex. instead, let's use Catmull-Rom curves, because they're defined as "the curve goes **through** the following points: ..." instead of being simply *controlled* by points.

For any 2 edges between 3 points, p1, p2 and p3, we can create new points p2l and p2r on the left and right of p2, along the edges p1--p2 and p2--p3, at a fixed distances "radius" from p2:

```
dx = p2.x-p1.x
dy = p2.y-p1.y
p2l = {x: p2.x - radius * dx, y: p2.y - radius * dy}
p2l_guide = {x: p2.x - 3 * radius * dx, y: p2.y - 3 * radius * dy}
```

and

```
dx = p3.x-p2.x
dy = p3.y-p2.y
p2r = {x: p2.x + radius * dx, y: p2.y + radius * dy}
p2r_guide = {x: p2.x + 3 * radius * dx, y: p2.y + 3 * radius * dy}
```

now our edges will look like p1--p2l and p2r--p3, and the trick is to "connect" p2l and p2r in a nice, arc-ish way. So let's use the `curveVertex`:

```
beginShape();
curveVertex(p2l_guide.x,p2l_guide.y);
curveVertex(p2l.x,p2l.y);
curveVertex(p2r.x,p2r.y)
curveVertex(p2r_guide.x,p2r_guide.y);
endShape();
```

Of course, you're dealing with lots of edge pairs, so you'll need to preprocess your list of coordinates to become lists of tubles {p2l_guide,p2l,p2r,p2r_guide} instead, and then connect those as straight line p2r(n)--p2l(n+1) and then add the connection curve from p2l to p2r guided by the ..._guide points. In code: http://jsfiddle.net/drzp6L0g/3

This solution does leave us with the mystery variable `f` that controls the guide strength, so to solve that we *would* need bezier curves, and we'd need to determine the same p2l and p2r points, and then apply [some trigonometry](http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#circles_cubic) to figure out what our control points would need to be in order to effect an approximation a of circular arc. It'd be more accurate, but also more work.

The ideal solution, of course, would be to simply use an arcTo command, but Processing doesn't actually have one. It has an [`arc()`](https://processing.org/reference/arc_.html) command, detached from creating shapes (so if you just need outlines... that might do just fine for you!) but if you need a filled shape, no luck.

Comment: That looks promising, thanks a lot! I'll give it a deeper look later and get back to mark your answer as correct.

Comment: I can extend the answer with the "real" cubic bezier answer with some more code later, too. The maths is involved, but known, so it's mostly "plug in the right values after making sure we copy the functions required correctly".

Comment: Thanks, go ahead if you want to extend the answer, but I think it's close enough. Right now I don't have the time to dig into it, that's why I was looking for a more straightforward-magical solution. But it doesn't seem to exist yet.

Comment: not just "yet", without an arc function in the beginShape/endShape set of commands, Processing simply can't do this "correctly".

Comment: actually, this answer is rather silly now that I think about it longer, because we don't want "circular" corners, we just want rounded corners. Bezier curves to "round off" isosceles triangles are actually really simple, so I'm going to give you a second answer that's going to be a hell of a lot easier than this one =)

Comment: It seems that "jsfiddle" service doesn't available in some countries.

Comment: thankfully the fiddle is just to illustrate the answer; it's convenient, but not necessary for the answer to stand on its own. Especially given the follow-up answer next to this one.

Answer (score 3):

Revisiting this, when we want rounded corners with "a radius" we don't actually want circular connections, we just want the isosceles triangle "tip" to be rounded off. That's actually really easy with Bezier curves, so here goes.

We still need our offset points p2l and p2r, because we're going to round off the triangle p2l--p2--p2r:

For any 2 edges between 3 points, p1, p2 and p3, we can create new points p2l and p2r on the left and right of p2, along the edges p1--p2 and p2--p3, at a fixed distances "radius" from p2:

```
dx = p2.x-p1.x
dy = p2.y-p1.y
p2l = {x: p2.x - radius * dx, y: p2.y - radius * dy}
```

and

```
dx = p3.x-p2.x
dy = p3.y-p2.y
p2r = {x: p2.x + radius * dx, y: p2.y + radius * dy}
```

(Note that we don't need any additional guide points). We can now define the rounding operation as:

```
start = p2l
c1 = point somewhere on line p2l--p2, ratio distance `t` from p2l and `1-t` from p2
c2 = point somewhere on line p2r--p2, using same ratio distance
end = p2r
```

If we pick a ratio distance of 0, then `c1 == p2l` and `c2 == p2r`, and we get a straight line. If we pick ratio distance 1, then `c1 == c2 == p2`, and we have the most pointy curve possible. For decent looking curves, a value of 0.5 or 0.75 will do the trick just fine. So first, let's define that c1/c2 abstracting function:

```
float[] roundIsosceles(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3, float t) {
  float mt = 1-t,
        c1x = (mt*p1.x + t*p2.x),
        c1y = (mt*p1.y + t*p2.y),
        c2x = (mt*p3.x + t*p2.x),  
        c2y = (mt*p3.y + t*p2.y);
  return new float[]{ c1x, c1y, c2x, c2y };
}
```

And now we can create out proper shape, based on the `closed` list of points:

```
beginShape();
Point p1,p2,p3;
for(int i=0, last=closed.size(); i<last; i+=3) {
  p1 = closed.get(i);
  p2 = closed.get(i+1);
  p3 = closed.get(i+2);

  // rounded isosceles triangle connector values:
  float[] c = roundIsosceles(p1, p2, p3, 0.75);

  // tell Processing that we have points to add to our shape:
  vertex(p1.x,p1.y);
  bezierVertex(c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3], p3.x, p3.y); 
}
endShape(CLOSE);
```

And done. What's the result? As running code, this: http://jsfiddle.net/drzp6L0g/13, and as picture, this:

[image]

And a simple demonstrator of the difference between ratios 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75 and 1:

[image]

Comment: This is a very clever way of using Catmull-Rom curve to achieve a rounding effect over a given "unrounded" polygon. But please be noted that the rounded corner is not a circular arc with specified radius.

Comment: These are true Bezier curves, not Catmull-Rom curves (both are Hermite curves, but they have different expression and abstraction methods). And you're right, this just yields nicely rounded corners, not true circular rounding based on the given radius. I might rework this answer a third time later =)