# Does DevExpress have anything similar to the Syncfusion BannerTextProvider?

Tags: winforms, devexpress, syncfusion

I would like to replace

```
Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.BannerTextProvider
Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.BannerTextInfo
```

with equivalent (or similar) DevExpress component or just System.Windows.Forms. Any suggestion please?

https://www.syncfusion.com/products/windows-forms/bannertextprovider

Comment: It's unclear what this Syncfusion components can do.

Comment: Why you downvoted my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771828/algorithm-for-creating-rounded-corners-in-a-polygon/24780108#24780108)?

Comment: Please contact Syncfusion support if you have any features that are missing in the BannerTextProvider or if you have any other questions. Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: It appears to be providing a watermark feature that is similar to the NullText property in the DevExpress editor controls.

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItem_NullTexttopic

Answer (score 0):

BannerTextProvider helps to customize the editor control appearance. You can also change the banner text color, Mode and etc.

BannerTextProvider includes the following modes.

**FocusMode:**  The banner text disappears when the control gets focus.

**EditMode:** The banner text disappears only when the control is in Edit Mode or when the associated textbox is not empty.

Please check below sample for your reference.

Sample link: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/BannerTextProvider-1042639859

UG link: http://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/bannertextprovider/overview

Could you please share us, what difficulty you are facing with Syncfusion BannerText Component? That will be helpful for us to analyze and provide solution.