# How do I draw a triangle with a corner radius?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I am trying to draw a triangle like this one exactly
[image]

Can someone guide me how to achieve this as I tried a lot with no success?

my worst case scenario is to use a image but I don't want to do that.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you demonstrate with a small code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771828/algorithm-for-creating-rounded-corners-in-a-polygon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should try this:

```
let trianglePath = UIBezierPath()
trianglePath.lineJoinStyle = .round
trianglePath.lineWidth = 25
trianglePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 5.0, y: 10.0)) 
trianglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 130, y: 280.0)) 
trianglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 265.0, y: 10.0)) 
trianglePath.close()
```

That gives you this in Playground:
[image]

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but how can I apply the color? I am not able to see any result when I run. Thanks!