# Draw the major arc given two endpoints and a center

Tags: java, geometry

I looked at the question here:  [Draw arc with 2 points and center of the circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196749/draw-arc-with-2-points-and-center-of-the-circle)
And it works perfectly, but I was wondering how I'd go about drawing the major arc associated with the points, rather than the minor one.

(Sorry about formatting, I'm on mobile)

Comment: Just exchange startAngle and endAngle arguments?

Comment: It's that simple? Cool!

Comment: I am not sure how exactly Java drawArc works, so you'd better to check.

Comment: Hmm. DrawArc appears to accept the starting angle, and then the total arc measure. In the docs, it states that positive values are Clockwise and negative are Anticlockwise. Therefore, it would be -(360 - endAngle) to get the proper measure.

Comment: That is why I was doubted. What version of drawArc (link to decription) are you using?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Arc2D.html#setArc(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20int) here. And the fact that drawArc simply creates an arc and sets it.